# Discord.js Report Command Error: Client is not definied

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was trying to make report command for my bot but when I ran it, it showed the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Client is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/lifeafterbot/commands/report.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at /home/runner/lifeafterbot/index.js:27:21
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/run_dir/interp.js:209:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
```

My current code is:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

Client.on('message', (message) => {
 let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ');
 switch (args[0]) {
  case 'report':
   message.delete({ timeout: 3000 });
   let target =
    message.mentions.members.first() ||
    message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
   if (!target)
    return message.channel
     .send('Please provide a user that you wish to report')
     .then((m) => m.delete({ timeout: 15000 }));

   let reason = args.slice(2).join(' ');
   if (!reason)
    return message.channel
     .send(`Please provide a reason for reporting **${target.user.username}**`)
     .then((m) => m.delete({ timeout: 15000 }));

   let reportChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(
    (x) => x.name === 'finished-applies'
   );

   message.channel
    .send(
     'Your report has been filed to the staff team. Thank you for reporting!'
    )
    .then((m) => m.delete({ timeout: 15000 }));
   reportChannel.send(
    `**${message.author.username}** has reported **${target.user.username}** for **${reason}**.`
   );
   break;
 }
});
```

Comment: `Client` is not defined in the code snippet you provided.

Comment: uhm i know but how can i fix it

Comment: please look at this [guide](https://discordjs.guide/#before-you-begin) and work through it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define "Client". You can do this by:

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
```